# How many rings are there of order 4 up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

> How many rings of order 4 can exist upto isomorphism

there are only two groups $Z_4$ and $K_4$ upto isomorphism where $Z_4$ is abelian and $K_4$ is non-abelian.To be a ring that must be a abelian group under one binary operation.Can it be say that $Z_4$ is only ring of order 4 upto isomorphism

Comment: What about the field of order $4$?

Comment: All groups of order $4$ are abelian... Maybe you meant that $K_4$ is not cyclic.